# Adding percentage text to progressbar C#

Tags: c#, progress-bar, windows-forms-designer, percentage

I have a method that shows when a process bar is in execution and when is successfully completed.

I worked fine, but I would like to add a percentage showing a 100% if is complete and less if it got stuck some where.

I have made several research online but I could not adapt anything to the solution that I am looking for.

This is my code:

```
private void progressBar()
{
    int i;

    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;

    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = i;               
    }
}
```

I use the method call on my execution button by calling it with the follow:

```
progressBar();
```

Thanks

Comment: Without updating the UI or doing some long-running operation, your for-loop is unnecessary and you could just write `progressBar1.Value = 100`, which would probably be what it is optimized to in release mode.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming this is a winforms project? Are you wanting to add a label somewhere that also shows the same progress bar value?

Comment: @RonBeyer. Thank you for the reply. In fact I have changed the first suggestion and you're right the for loop is unnecessary. Second it is a Windows Form and I would like to also add a label to the progress bar value. Thanks

Comment: try to use progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(your configurations)

Comment: @Chase thank you you were right. I will submit my solution. It worked

Comment: this implementation is wrong, How do you know that the task is done when i = 100?

Answer (score 2):

I have adjust the prograssBar method with the following lines.

The solution works.

Thanks

```
int percent = (int)(((double)progressBar1.Value / (double)progressBar1.Maximum) * 100);
            progressBar1.Refresh();
            progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular),
                Brushes.Black,
                new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7));
```

Comment: That only updates the progressbar, the rest of your form would be block

Comment: @HosseinShahdoost, can you please point me how to make the changes according to your suggestions?. Thanks

Comment: @HosseinShahdoost I have another method that is importing data to a data base At the end of the main method I wanted to indicate the progress status bar

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement the progress in your operation, the operation's length must be calculated first. if it's not possible, you can't show a progress bar for that operation. (maybe only a loading gif)

but if so, There is an interface (**IProgress**) which can help you implement the progress reports.

First thing you should know, You must do the main task on another thread, and report the progress to the UI Thread. a simple example of this work would be something like this.

Progress.cs

```
public class Progress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    private readonly Action<T> _progressAction;

    public Progress(Action<T> action)
    {
        _progressAction = action;
    }

    public void Report(T value)
    {
        _progressAction?.Invoke(value);
    }
}
```

Your code would be like this, in which the task starts after you click a button named ButtonBase

```
Progress<int> MyProgressObject { get; set; }

private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyProgressObject = new Progress<int>(ProgressAction);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TimeConsumingTask);
}

public void TimeConsumingTask(object state)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        MyProgressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ProgressAction(i));
    }
}

public void ProgressAction(int progress)
{
    MyProgressBar.Value = progress;
}
```

I know It might look difficult but this is the proper way of doing time consuming tasks and prevent UI block

Answer (score 0):

If you use it as a part of backgroundworker it works perfectly
I added a Label in the middle of the progressbar

And i added last row in my  bgw_ProgressChanged method

```
    private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        p_bar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        fnameLbl.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
        percentLbl.Text = "%" + (e.ProgressPercentage).ToString();
    }
```

ProgressPercentagevalue comes from the method below

```
        foreach (var item in filebox1)
        {
            System.IO.File.Move(item, Path.Combine(destdir, Path.GetFileName(item)));
            ++counter;
            int tmp = (int)((counter* 100) / totfiles);
            bgw.ReportProgress(tmp, "File transfered : " + Path.GetFileName(item));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
```

Totfiles is the number of files that I get from server.

Thread.Sleep(100) let's you see for a short time what is displayed with fnameLbl.Text

Answer (score 0):

```
int total = ;
int val = ;

double createDivider = total / 100;
int percent = val / createDivider;
```

this value (percent) is the right percent '%' of total